# Display issue NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 on HDMI - blue tint on some 1080p web videos/video files/games/etc

Tags: video, display, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, youtube

I've been using my PC connected to my 50" TV for the past couple of months and an odd seemingly random issue started happening (which did not happen until then, while it was connected to a VGA monitor with a DVI-to-VGA adapter). Sometimes, when playing certain youtube videos, the tv would turn black for half a second and then it would display everything in a bluish tint.

The effect is more than that but hard to describe specifically. The display also turns less sharp, it looks like how it'd look if the wrong refresh rate was being used, and the edges of objects, people, etc on the screen sort of look like they lack antialiasing or something (I'm not talking about games, I'm just trying to describe what the change looks like visually). Also, the mouse pointer starts moving slower, like it’s lagging a bit. Another effect, which is especially visible on videos whcih trigger the issue, is that the framerate seems to increase somehow, though it's inconsistent, mkaing things in the video appear to move smoother, sort of like the "100HZ Motion Plus" effect on Samsung TVs. If I close the video the screen pops to black for a half second and then everything is normal again.

Having since investigate further, the issue proved not to be random, but despite the many systematic triggers and information I've found, I've yet to discern a common cause for it. Here are the separate and disparate pieces of information I've managed to find:

- The video card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 and it's connected via HDMI to a 50" Sony Bravia TV.
- I've excluded the tv or cable as a cause because I've connected them to 2 other computers and ran the same videos and the issue did not manifest.
- Also I've connected the PC to the monitor again with the DVI-VGA adapter and the issue didn't appear
- I've also connected both HDMI TV and DVI/VGA monitor and something interesting happens. If I set them as extended displays, and i start the video while it's on the monitor, nothing happens, but if I drag the video to the TV while it's running it'll trigger the issue, only on the tv. not only this, but if I then close the video the issue does not dissappear from the tv. It stays there until I refresh the display somehow (like changing the resolution), If they're cloned, the issue manifests on the tv instantly and the same refresh is needed to reset it.
- The issue only appears on 1080p video(s). If I change it to 720p (such as a youtube video) the display becomes normal again.
- it happens on videos in web broser, video files (I've only tried mkv) and games. Each time it's only on some files/videos/games.
- with web videos: regardless of which web browser I use, some videos on youtube (but not only youtube, this can happen on any page with a video, like vimeo etc) will trigger the error when at 1080p. these videos will consistently trigger the error each time they are run. However, as mentioned, this only happens to some videos, and I could not find a pattern between the videos because it even differs on videos from the same channel, posted only about a day apart.
- with video files: it's happened with at least one 1080p mkv file, but not with others. Closing the file resolves the issue.
- with games: as an example, it's happened with one game (Divinity - Original Sin) set to 1080p, but not another (Wolfenstein New Order). Both pretty visually demanding games. It's interesing with Divinity because it only triggers if the game is fullscreen. If I change it to windowed, but still 1080p, the issue dissappears. It's interesting because with web videos/mkv files the issue happens regardless of whether the video is fullscreen or not.
- I can’t share a screenshot of how it looks like because I’ve tried taking one and, when I look at it without the issue manifesting, the image I’ve captured looks normal. I’d have to take a photo (or video) of the screen with a camera, but I’m not sure how perceptible the issue would be.
- I've uninstalled and re-installed the graphic card's driver but nothing changed. I've also checked that it's the only display driver installed.
- the weirdest part is that if I safe boot the issue manifests continuously, from the moment it boots up!

Any ideas what might be causing this or suggestions on what I could try to either fix/prevent the issue or try to find out what's causing it? Let me know if you need me to provide any other info.

Comment: Try to disable GSYNC with Nvidia Inspector .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it hasn't worked and I have yet to find a solution. Any ideas what I could do to at least attract more replies?